# Missing function definitions with libcurl-devel on CentOS 6.6

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, curl

I am having trouble compiling my program which uses libcurl.

The environment I am using is CentOS 6.6 on a VM, and I am getting errors which suggests that the library has either:

1. not installed correctly or
2. cannot be found.

I did a

- `sudo yum install libcurl` followed by a
- `sudo yum install libcurl-devel` followed by a
- `sudo yum update`

It seems that the `curl.h` has been put under `/usr/include/curl` which seems correct so I am unsure as to why this has occurred.

It is worth noting that a test program with `#include <curl/curl.h>` is compiling.

Also, when libcurl-devel is not installed (and only libcurl is),

- gcc complained it couldn't find `curl.h`, as expected,
- there was also no curl directory under `/usr/include/`, as expected,
- however libcurl did install a curl file under `/usr/bin/`, as expected.

In Ubuntu I only had to install libcurl-openssl

Some example gcc errors:

```
$gcc new.c -lcurl
new.c: In function ‘main’:
new.c:74: error: ‘CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM’ undeclared (first use in this function)
new.c:74: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
new.c:74: error: for each function it appears in.)
new.c:81: error: ‘CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Comment: Did you include `curl.h` in your program?

Comment: If yes, examine curl.h if it really contains `CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM` and `CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT`. if not you're probably just using a wrong Version of curl.

Comment: I did `#include <curl/curl.h>`

Comment: seems like these don't exist within curl.h - I don't suppose you could suggest the correct version? As mentioned I was using libcurl-openssl in ubuntu

Comment: Maybe you can try executing `apt-get show libcurl-openssl` to find the right Version on the running box

Comment: apt-get show? The box is running centos 6.6, my desktop however (working copy) is running ubuntu with libcurl4-openssl, this package is for ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah i meant the ubuntu box. So you need to have curl4 and its dev files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are installing libcurl-devel from the CentOS RPM then it absolutely should *not* be putting the header, or anything else, in `/usr/local/curl`.  `/usr/local` is for locally-built components, not for components provided by the OS.  Exactly what that means can be a subject for debate, but I can confirm that the CentOS 6 RPM for libcurl-devel installs the headers in `/usr/include/curl`.

With that being the case, if CentOS's `libcurl-devel` is installed, then you shouldn't need any special compiler flags to get the compiler to resolve

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

correctly, but if you happen to have a different `curl.h` somewhere on your system then you could cause it to be chosen instead.  Still, although I could maybe believe the compiler finding `/usr/local/include/curl/curl.h` automatically (that is, without `-I/usr/local/include`), I would be very surprised to hear that it finds `/usr/local/curl/curl.h` automatically.

But that probably isn't your problem.  CentOS 6 provides version 7.19 of libcurl.  That version does not provide the macros you are trying to use, at least not in libcurl-devel.  I have checked for a possible add-on package corresponding to Ubuntu's libcurl-openssl, but there is no CentOS 6 package (or EPEL/el6 package) that has both "curl" and "ssl" in its name.

If you can identify what minimum version of libcurl you need, you can probably build it yourself.  In such cases I prefer to take a source RPM from [Fedora's Koji system](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=415), build RPMs from it on the local system, and install them (possibly updating existing RPMs in the process).  Alternatively, you can probably build and use a private copy, but in that case you will want to link it statically into your program.

Comment: Are there any alternatives other than curl that you know of for sending emails using SMTP in centos ?

Comment: @WilliamPaul, I added some comments about how you might get the desired version of libcurl.

Comment: For what it's worth, it appears that Curl initially added SMTP support in version 7.20, though the change log records quite a few bug fixes and enhancements since that initial release.

Comment: I have found an alternative solution, thank you for the help

Comment: I do not know how any Ubuntu sources might correspond.